# OrientDB: UPDATE query result in distributed mode

Tags: java, orientdb

I have a scheme-less class in my OrientDB, let's say it called 'testClass', it's pretty simple and contains 1 boolean property:

```
{
    lock : 'true'
}
```

When I execute update query via console or web ui:

```
update testClass set lock = true
```

i've got

```
Updated record(s) '1' in 0.033000 sec(s).
```

from console and similar result from web ui.

The same result i've got when I execute following Java code

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = ... // open db connection
Object result = db.command(new OCommandSQL("update testClass set lock = true")).execute()
```

The 'result' variable is of type Integer and contains number of updated record.

But everything changes when the OrientDB server is started in distributed mode (I have 3 nodes). The execution of the same query from console produceds:

```
Updated record(s) '[null]' in 0.010000 sec(s).
```

As you can see, now the result is an array and it's empty. The same I've got from Java - the 'result' variable is of type ArrayList and it's empty.
The most interesting result shows web ui - when I execute the same query, I've got '[1]' in 'value' column, which means, I guess, that result is array and it contain 1 integer value '1'.

Is it a feature or a bug? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is due to the fact in distributed mode you got the "reduce" result, but for an unknown reason is not managed correctly in console. Is the record updated?

Comment: Yes, the record in DB is updated. The most important thing for me was to get number of updated records in Java code because I tried to implement simple optimistic lock for distributed application. Original query was "update testClass set lock = true where lock = false"

Comment: This has been fixed in last 2.1.x branch.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the guide http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Update.html
try this query
update testClass set lock = true return after @rid

Comment: Thanks! It's not exactly what I wanted, but it may help